# pdfpages does not correctly scale inserted pdf pages

Tags: pdfpages, pandoc

I use the following code :

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
...
\includepdf[pages=-]{article.pdf}
```

I also tried many `pdfpages` options such as `fitpaper`, `templatesize`, `noautoscale`, `scale` and so forth.

I also tried with other pdf files.

The result is always the same, I have the correct amount of page inserted in my final pdf but each of them and incredibly small.

[image]

Comment: Give "thumbnails" a new meaning. Did you try with some other pdf-file? Did you try to scale the pages (scale=10 or so)?

Comment: Yes I also tried `scale=10` and also others pdf files with the same result.

Comment: Other pdf files from the same source? What happens when you try an image from the mwe package with `\includepdf{example-image}`? Can you make a small but complete example and show the code and the log file?

Comment: I found the command which is responible for the small scaling : `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}`. This is generated by `pandoc` and I also found an old bug submitted there https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/issues/72

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a known pandoc issue : https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/issues/72

To resolve it you need to use your own template. Use `pandoc -D latex > template.tex` to generate it. Then find the following line :

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\ScaleWidthIfNeeded,height=\ScaleHeightIfNeeded,keepaspectratio}%
```

and comment it.

Next, call `pandoc` with this argument : `--template=template.tex`

Works like a charm for me.

Comment: The only thing is that removing this line make all the figure to not automatically scale well according to page size... :-(